# How to get a mod rewrite rewritecond to do '(A and B) or (C and D)' instead of 'A and (B or C) and D'?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get a bunch of rewrite conditions to evaluate like so:

`(A and B) or (C and D)`

Here is the format I tried:

```
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B [OR]
RewriteCond C
RewriteCond D
```

However, due to `OR` having a higher precedence this evaluates as

`A and (B or C) and D`

Is it possible to group these as above instead?

Comment: My initial thought is to use the `<if></if>` and `<else></else>` directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use temporary environment variables:

```
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B
RewriteRule ^ - [E=PART1:TRUE]

RewriteCond C
RewriteCond D
RewriteRule ^ - [E=PART2:TRUE]

RewriteCond %{ENV:PART1} =TRUE [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:PART2} =TRUE
RewriteRule ...
```